# Django automatic login after signup

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get users automatically logged in after registration. However the user only seems to be logged in for the duration of rendering the next html page (`user.is_authenticated` returns True in my templates) and gets logged out immediatly after (`request.user` returns AnonymousUser in a method I call via AJAX on the next page - moving to another page also makes clear you are not logged in anymore since my templates render the login instead of the logout links again). If I try the commented code instead `authenticate()` always returns NONE.

What am I doing wrong?

```
def signup_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserSignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            send_confirmation_email(user, current_site.domain)
            # user_login = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], password=form.cleaned_data['password1'])
            # login(request, user_login)
            login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
            args = {'user': user}
            return render(request, 'accounts/signup_success.html', args)
    else:
        form = UserSignUpForm()
    args = {'form': form, 'project_name': settings.PROJECT_NAME}
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', args)
```

Comment: if you are setting `user.is_active = False` then user wont be able to login.

Comment: i dont believe that. it works for inactive users if i use my login page, which basically does the same as the commented code. But I'll try.

Comment: `user.is_active = False` is set. Why is set to False when you are expecting the user to be logged in?. Try changing to True and uncomment the `authenticate()` function.

Comment: Damn it works and it actually makes sense. But how do I achieve to auto login a user and also making him confirm his email address

Comment: I haven't tried this suggestion. But you can try the same or similar approach. You can send email to confirm and set session expiry to logout. Once the user clicked confirmation, update some falg as is_confirmed , similiar to is_active, and expire session to logout (client side and server side logic as well). Hope this helps.

Comment: Would you be open to using Django Allauth package or a similar package? With allauth, I know that these problems are handled and you would be making these decisions (e.g. auto login after signup) via django settings instead of via code. Confirmation email is also a feature...

Answer (score 0):

Please use following lines of code. It may full fill your requirements.

```
def signup(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('records:dashboard')
else:
    form = UserCreationForm()
return render(request, 'registration/signup.html', {'form': form})
```